# jQUery append .html(data) how can i append it without overlapping my first append?

Tags: jquery

how can i append my div, without overlapping or overwrite my first append?

is my jQuery code correct?

```
$(function() {
    $(".videoThumbS").live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataString = $(this).siblings('input[name="v_w_id"]').val();
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST',                                  
            url: 'api.php',
            data: { v_w_id: dataString },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                var viewrecord = dataString;
                $('.selected_thumbs').append('<div id=".new_thumb"></div>').html(data);

                $("."+viewrecord).hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

my button
`<input class="videoThumbS" type="button" name="selectSel" value="Select" id="selectbut" />`

and the div that it will display
`<div class="selected_thumbs"></div>`

do i need to create a new div?
what do i need to do so that it wont overlap...

my sample website is this. http://cocopop12.site11.com/v2.2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('.selected_thumbs').append($('<div id=".new_thumb"></div>').html(data));
```

Comment: @user1506189: that is not the way of thanking in stack overflow :)

Comment: @user1506189 If it works, give a vote up and put a tick to the answer so that others know the answer.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal, I didn't downvote this post. (: and I can't tell why this has been downvoted.

Comment: @mauris, No worries. just ask since your comment time and the down voting time matched :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
$('.selected_thumbs').append('<div id=".new_thumb">' + data + '</div>');
```